# 2 same sql request, one long and one short

Tags: mysql, sql

I build an sql request, and this one works well with one set on datas, but it is very long with an an other one even if the amount of datas is almost the same.

Here is the request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PIECES.PICLEUNIK AS PICLEUNIK,
PIECES.HORSLISTE AS HL,
PIECES.REFCONSTRU AS REFCONSTRU,
PIECES.REFINTERNE AS REFINTERNE,
FOURNISS.NOM AS NOM,
STOCKPIE.QTSTOCK AS QTSTOCK,
STOCKPIE.CASIER AS CASIER,
STOCKPIE.CLEPIEMAGA AS CLEPIEMAGA,
STOCKPIE.STCLEUNIK AS STCLEUNIK,
STOCKPIE.PICLEUNIK AS PICLEUNIK2

FROM  PIECES 
RIGHT JOIN STOCKPIE ON STOCKPIE.PICLEUNIK=PIECES.PICLEUNIK  -
LEFT JOIN CONSTRUC ON CONSTRUC.COCLEUNIK = PIECES.COCLEUNIK
LEFT JOIN FOURNISS ON FOURNISS.FOCLEUNIK = PIECES.FOCLEUNIK

WHERE  
STOCKPIE.MGCLEUNIK=1
ORDER BY  STCLEUNIK 
LIMIT 300
```

Here is the explain of the first request, which is very long (13 seconds):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<explain>
  <plan type="limit">
    <type>top</type>
    <rows>300</rows>
    <plan type="sort">
      <sort-key>
        <item>STCLEUNIK</item>
      </sort-key>
      <plan type="materialize">
        <plan type="join">
          <join-method>nestedloops</join-method>
          <join-type>left</join-type>
          <plan type="table">
            <name>STOCKPIE</name>
            <filter>( STOCKPIE.MGCLEUNIK =  1) </filter>
            <index-scan key="MGCLEUNIK"/>
          </plan>
          <plan type="join">
            <join-method>nestedloops</join-method>
            <join-type>left</join-type>
            <plan type="join">
              <join-method>nestedloops</join-method>
              <join-type>left</join-type>
              <plan type="table">
                <name>PIECES</name>
                <filter>( STOCKPIE.PICLEUNIK = PIECES.PICLEUNIK ) </filter>
                <index-scan key="PICLEUNIK"/>
              </plan>
              <plan type="table">
                <name>FOURNISS</name>
                <filter>( FOURNISS.FOCLEUNIK = PIECES.FOCLEUNIK ) </filter>
                <index-scan key="FOCLEUNIK"/>
              </plan>
            </plan>
            <plan type="table">
              <name>CONSTRUC</name>
              <filter>( CONSTRUC.COCLEUNIK = PIECES.COCLEUNIK ) </filter>
              <index-scan key="COCLEUNIK"/>
            </plan>
          </plan>
        </plan>
      </plan>
    </plan>
  </plan>
</explain>
```

Here is the explain of the second one, very short (0.06 second):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<explain>
  <plan type="materialize">
    <plan type="limit">
      <type>top</type>
      <rows>300</rows>
      <plan type="join">
        <join-method>nestedloops</join-method>
        <join-type>left</join-type>
        <plan type="table">
          <name>STOCKPIE</name>
          <filter>( STOCKPIE.MGCLEUNIK =  1) </filter>
          <index-scan key="STCLEUNIK"/>
        </plan>
        <plan type="join">
          <join-method>nestedloops</join-method>
          <join-type>left</join-type>
          <plan type="join">
            <join-method>nestedloops</join-method>
            <join-type>left</join-type>
            <plan type="table">
              <name>PIECES</name>
              <filter>( STOCKPIE.PICLEUNIK = PIECES.PICLEUNIK ) </filter>
              <index-scan key="PICLEUNIK"/>
            </plan>
            <plan type="table">
              <name>FOURNISS</name>
              <filter>( FOURNISS.FOCLEUNIK = PIECES.FOCLEUNIK ) </filter>
              <index-scan key="FOCLEUNIK"/>
            </plan>
          </plan>
          <plan type="table">
            <name>CONSTRUC</name>
            <filter>( CONSTRUC.COCLEUNIK = PIECES.COCLEUNIK ) </filter>
            <index-scan key="COCLEUNIK"/>
          </plan>
        </plan>
      </plan>
    </plan>
  </plan>
</explain>
```

The difference between the 2 seems to be the the beginning: other plan type is a sort one for the long request:

```
       <plan type="sort">
      <sort-key>
        <item>STCLEUNIK</item>
      </sort-key>
      <plan type="materialize">
        <plan type="join">
          <join-method>nestedloops</join-method>
          <join-type>left</join-type>
          <plan type="table">
            <name>STOCKPIE</name>
            <filter>( STOCKPIE.MGCLEUNIK =  1) </filter>
            <index-scan key="MGCLEUNIK"/>
```

And a join type for the short one:

```
      <plan type="join">
        <join-method>nestedloops</join-method>
        <join-type>left</join-type>
        <plan type="table">
          <name>STOCKPIE</name>
          <filter>( STOCKPIE.MGCLEUNIK =  1) </filter>
          <index-scan key="STCLEUNIK"/>
        </plan>
```

Why do these same request are executed differently? How can I make the first request to execute the same way as the second one to improve the speed?

Comment: first tag your dbms, and if you can please show the execution plan in text format.

Comment: also we miss a lots of data like time, cost, etc.

Comment: Any chances to have that explain in `json` instead of `xml`?

Comment: "Why do these same request are executed differently?" Apparently there are different statistics for your datasets so the planner choses a different execution plan. Did you run `analyze` for both of them?

Comment: Also, does these times are such in every run?

Comment: And for me it seems like you didn't have `ORDER BY  STCLEUNIK ` in that faster run.

Comment: Yes, these time are for every run. The request are exactly the same but it seems indeed that the faster one does not run the order by the same way as the first one.
And sorry I only have the explain in xml

Comment: Please try with `explain format=json select...`.

Comment: I assume that there are different tables. Did you run `analyze table` on them, just in case if this is about wrong statistic? And you could also show what is in there for these tables: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-statistics-table.html

Comment: You write about two datasets. Is it the same version of mysql?